# Data Collection From Client Side

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, excel, data

I'm working with Sharepoint online, and have the need to collect simple numerical data from user's clients/browser. The user takes an action (selects a number), and then that number should be recorded and stored. The server is Microsoft hosted, meaning I can't run server side code. Aside from Sharepoint lists, I'm unaware of any way to store data on the server through client side code. What options, if any, are there for storing data points on the Sharepoint server through client side code interactions? Is it possible to modify server-side excel documents or anything like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wanna fetching data ?

Comment: @Mathew Writing data is the main requirement, although I may want to fetch as well... It's not required, though.